# java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream from API response

Tags: inputstream, httpresponse, bufferedreader, gzipstream, gzipinputstream

> `URL url = new URL("https://api.sep.abc/stream/streamid/channelid?connectionTimeout=30");
> HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
> http.setRequestMethod("POST");
> http.setDoOutput(true);
> http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
> http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/x-ndjson");
> http.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
> http.setRequestProperty("authorization", "{bearer token}");
>
> String data = "{\n"next": "NGE0YjRhMTYtMTgyOC00ZTdjLTgwZTE"\n}";
>
> byte[] out = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
>
> OutputStream stream = http.getOutputStream();
> stream.write(out);
> InputStream stream = http.getInputStream();
> GZIPInputStream gz = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
> BufferedReader reader4 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gz));
>
> StringBuilder stringBuilder3 = new StringBuilder();
> String line3;
>
> Read the response from the server line by line
>
> while ((line3 = reader4.readLine()) != null) {
> System.out.println(line3);
> }
>
> `

I am trying to read a zipped streaming data from an api and while extracting, I am getting a json data but suddenly it runs into

> java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream error.

can anyone please let me know if anything is wrong here or how to resolve this error.